# every data type reserves a memory or address in array but why don't comma(,) reserve its memory in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
main()
{
    int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int *ptr;
    ptr=&arr[0];
    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    ptr=&arr[1];
    cout<<ptr<<endl;
    cout<<*ptr;
}
```

As in the above program i have printed some addresses and a value from the array and they have reserved some memory but ","separator don't reserve any memory in the array why according to the logic it should have to reserve some memory or any sort of address.
Does these separators reserve any memory or address? if they do so why can't we print them.

Comment: They don't. `int arr[5]={1,2,3,4,5};` only reserves space for those 5 numbers. The commas are there because otherwise it would be int `arr[5]={12345};` and that would do something very different (it would do the same as `int arr[5]={12345, 0, 0, 0, 0};`).

Comment: its similar to integers not storing a `;` but to declare one you write `int x = 5;`, one is syntax the other is what is actually stored in the bits of your computers memory

Comment: The commas are only there to allow the compiler to tell where one number ends and the next begins. It is the numbers that are stored in the array.

Comment: BTW, you could let the compiler determine the size of the array:  `int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`.  The size is defined as `size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);`.  This allows you to add or remove elements of the array without affecting the rest of the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do not.

The separators are never stored in the array. The array consists of a continous block of memmory and the datatype of the array lets us know how much of that block each element occupies as the size of the array type is statically known.